# How to subnet home network

Tags: routing, switch, hp

I have just bought an HP A5120-24G EI TAA (JG245) switch for my home network; this is a layer 2 and layer 3 capable switch. I would like to create some vlans or to subnet my network so that my two Windows XP PCs can access our NAS and our network printers but not Internet, and my Linux PC can access our NAS, our network printers and Internet but not my Windows XP PCs, and our Wi-Fi devices can access Internet, our NAS, our network printers but not my wire connected PCs.

How can I do that? Do I need to buy a router?

Comment: the required configuration will depend on your switch if it is support ACL or not

Comment: Yes, my switch supports ACL. From the product data sheet: Provide IP Layer 2 to Layer 4 traffic filtering; and supports global ACL, VLAN ACL, port ACL,
and IPv6 ACL

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 5120 is a layer 3 switch, you can use it as router.

- Add VLANs and assign them to ports as required.
- Add IP addresses to VLANs (e.g. 192.168.x.1 for each VLAN x). They act as default gateways for all devices in each subnet.
- Add a default gateway to the router VLAN pointing to the Internet gateway.
- Turn on IP routing.
- Add ACLs to allow your XP client subnet to access the subnets they need, allow the other subnets to access everything and block everything else.
- On the router, add routes for your VLANs. You can use a single route if you subnetted (192.168.0.0/16 -> 192.168.1.1 when the router VLAN is 1).